# Regex Findall With Mismatch Using Variables

Tags: python, regex

The following code works great

```
sequence = 'TATTGCTGATCAGTGGCCTAGCTAAAGTA'
m = regex.findall('(CCTC){s<=1}', sequence)
```

However, I need to alter it so that I am searching for a variable instead of CCTC. So something like

```
sequence = 'TATTGCTGATCAGTGGCCTAGCTAAAGTA'
m = regex.findall('(myvar){s<=1}', sequence)
```

I have tried the following, but it seems to only return perfect matches

```
myvar = 'CCTC' + '{s<=3}'
sequence = 'TATTGCTGATCAGTGGCCTAGCTAAAGTA'
m = regex.findall(myvar, sequence)
```

How do I use a variable with regex while allowing mismatches?

Comment: Both top and bottom snippets return the exact same thing to me, even when changing `{s<=3}` to `{s<=1}`.

Comment: `myvar = 'CCTC' + '{s<=3}'`: round brackets are missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
dynamic_param = "CCTC"
m = regex.findall(r"(" + dynamic_param+ "){s<=1}", sequence)
```